# The request success in slave but the response body is empty in host

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, distributed, jmeter-5.0

Steps:
1. Configure the jmeter host and slave via the document
2. Run jmeter in distributed mode
3. Check the result in view result tree

Result:
1. The request shows success but when response body is empty in View Result Tree
2. at the slave I check the jmeter-server.log but there is no errors

[image: Empty reponse]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JMeter in distributed mode, by default, [doesn't send response data](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#sendermode) in order to consume less memory and not to effect performance

> Listeners in the test plan send their results back to the client JMeter which writes the results to the specified files By default, samples are sent back synchronously as they are generated. This can affect the maximum throughput of the server test

If you want to see resoonses, then you need to change mode to `Standard`

> mode
>   sample sending mode - default is StrippedBatch
>
> Standard
>   send samples synchronously as soon as they are generated

Or not Stripped mode, as [Batch](https://gerardnico.com/jmeter/remote#remote_batching)

> Stripped mode family strips responseData so this means that some Elements that rely on the previous responseData being available will not work.